# How to add nested childTemplates inside titanium android listView?

Tags: javascript, android, listview, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have code like this:

```
    var listViewRowTemplate = {
        properties: {
            height: '100dp'
        },
        childTemplates: [
            {
                //lblIndicator
                type: 'Ti.UI.Label',
                bindId:'lblIndicator',
                properties: {}
            },
            {
                //lblCustomer
                type: 'Ti.UI.Label',
                bindId:'lblCustomer',
                properties: {}
            },
            {
                //menu View
                type: 'Ti.UI.View',
                bindId:'menuView',
                properties: {},
                childTemplates: [
                    {
                        //lblName
                        type: 'Ti.UI.Label',
                        bindId:'lblName',
                        properties: {}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    var section = Ti.UI.createListSection({});
    var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({
        top:'175dp',
        height:Ti.UI.FILL,
        templates: { 'listViewRowTemplate': listViewRowTemplate },
        sections: [ section ]
    });
```

and i fill that listView with this code:

```
var listViewRow;


        listViewRow = {
            template:'listViewRowTemplate',
            properties:{backgroundColor:'green'},
            _data:myData,
            lblIndicator:_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('label.normal'), {
                _id:'indicator',
                left:'10dp',
                backgroundImage:bgIndicator,
                backgroundSelectedImage:bgIndicatorHover,
                height:'40dp',
                width:'40dp',
                top:'5dp'
            }),
            lblCustomer:_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('label.normal'), {
                _id:'customer',
                text:myData[i].CustomerShortDesc,
                left:'50dp',
                top:'0dp',
                height:'50dp'
            }),
            menuView:_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('view.tableview.header'), {
                _id:'menu',
                left:'10dp',
                height:'40dp',
                width:_globals.get('app.platformWidth') * 0.7,
                top:'50dp',
                lblName:_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('label.normal'), {
                    _id:'name',
                    left:'10dp',
                    text:'This is for name',
                    color:'red',
                    height:'40dp',
                    width:'40dp',
                    top:'5dp'
                })
            })
        };

        listViewData.push(listViewRow);

        section.setItems(listViewData);
```

For your info, `_globals.get()` and `_styles.get()` is my own custom JS file that return properties or object.

i can see my other component like lblIndicator, lblCustomer, and menuView, but not my nested component (lblName)..

Does anyone know how to fill listview with a nested component (childTemplates inside childTemplates)?

Please give me some suggestion.. Many thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution..
here's the working code :

```
var listViewRow;


        listViewRow = {
            template:'listViewRowTemplate',
            properties:{backgroundColor:'green'},
            _data:myData,
            lblIndicator:_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('label.normal'), {
                _id:'indicator',
                left:'10dp',
                backgroundImage:bgIndicator,
                backgroundSelectedImage:bgIndicatorHover,
                height:'40dp',
                width:'40dp',
                top:'5dp'
            }),
            lblCustomer:_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('label.normal'), {
                _id:'customer',
                text:myData[i].CustomerShortDesc,
                left:'50dp',
                top:'0dp',
                height:'50dp'
            }),
            menuView:_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('view.tableview.header'), {
                _id:'menu',
                left:'10dp',
                height:'40dp',
                width:_globals.get('app.platformWidth') * 0.7,
                top:'50dp'
            }),
            lblName:_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('label.normal'), {
                _id:'name',
                left:'10dp',
                text:'This is for name',
                color:'red',
                height:'40dp',
                width:'40dp',
                top:'5dp'
            })
        };

        listViewData.push(listViewRow);

        section.setItems(listViewData);
```

Many Thanks.. Hope it's helps..